# "I scream, you scream, we all scream for ice cream"- Is there a term that describes this 'word play'?

Tags: terminology, puns

What is the term that describes the word play found below?

> “I scream, you scream, we all scream for ice cream”

Another example might be the punchline: "Orange you glad to see me"?

Comment: the “lowest and most groveling kind of wit." ... a pun.

Comment: @Mitch: This is a concise answer. Why don't you submit it as such?

Comment: @Irene: I didn't want to put in the time to make it a worthwhile answer. Others have done so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answers have noted, these are examples of [puns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun).

> The pun, also called *paronomasia*, is a form of word play which
>   suggests two or more meanings, by exploiting multiple meanings of
>   words, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or
>   rhetorical effect. These ambiguities can arise from the intentional
>   use and abuse of homophonic, homographic, metonymic, or metaphorical
>   language.

But what sort of puns? The Reader's Digest condensed version ("What's that?") of the Wikipedia article may help us decide:

> Puns can be classified in various ways:
>
> The **homophonic** pun, a common type, uses word pairs which sound alike
>   (homophones) but are not synonymous. For example, in George Carlin's
>   phrase "Atheism is a non-prophet institution", the word "prophet" is
>   put in place of its homophone "profit", altering the common phrase
>   "non-profit institution".
>
> A **homographic** pun exploits words which are spelled the same
>   (homographs) but possess different meanings and sounds. Because of
>   their nature, they rely on sight more than hearing, contrary to
>   homophonic puns. An example which combines homophonic and homographic
>   punning is Douglas Adams's line "You can tune a guitar, but you can't
>   *tuna* fish. Unless of course, you play *bass*."
>
> **Homonymic** puns, another common type, arise from the exploitation of
>   words which are both homographs and homophones. The statement "Being
>   in politics is just like playing golf: you are trapped in one bad *lie*
>   after another" puns on the two meanings of the word lie as "a
>   deliberate untruth" and as "the position in which something rests".
>
> A **compound** pun is a statement that contains two or more puns. For
>   example, a complex statement by Richard Whately includes four puns:
>   "Why can a man never starve in the Great Desert? Because he can eat
>   the sand which is there. But what brought the sandwiches there? Why,
>   Noah sent Ham, and his descendants mustered and bred." This pun uses
>   "sand which is there/sandwiches there, "Ham/ham", "mustered/mustard",
>   and "bred/bread". Compound puns may also combine two phrases that
>   share a word. For example, "Where do mathematicians go on weekends? To
>   a Möbius strip club!" puns on Möbius strip and strip club.
>
> A **recursive** pun is one in which the second aspect of a pun relies on
>   the understanding of an element in the first. For example the
>   statement "π is only half a *pie*." (π radians is 180 degrees, or half a
>   circle, and a pie is a complete circle). Another example is "Infinity
>   is not *in finity*," which means infinity is not in finite range.
>   Another example is "A Freudian slip is when you say one thing but mean
>   your mother." Finally, we are given "Immanuel doesn't pun, he Kant" by
>   Oscar Wilde.

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is [*pun*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun?show=0&t=1321557774):

> **pun** *noun* \ˈpən\: the usually humorous use of a word in such a way as to suggest two or more of its meanings or the meaning of another word similar in sound.

Answer (score 0):

The first is as much alliteration as pun and since puns were good enough for Shakespeare and others of that ilk I'm happy to lower my standards to theirs.

"An we be in choler, we'll draw"