# A pun or not a pun?

Tags: puns, antanaclasis

I was talking to someone about puns and she said that it's a play on words, 
e.g. "those two pears are a pear of green balls" (sorry about the awful example, I couldn't think of any others on the spot).

I argued that this is a pun:

John Lydon looked out of his bedroom window and said, "Ah, how I love country life". (John Lydon stars in a butter advert which has the phrase "country life" in it).

Which is a pun?

Comment: See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/48697/5822) good answer for a breakdown of types of puns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How I love the country life" is a pun, because in that context 'country life' has two meanings — life in the country and the margarine brand.

"Those two pears are a pear of green balls" doesn't look like a pun to me, as nothing in there has two meanings.

Answer (score 4):

Both qualify as puns. I think you meant to say, "those two *pears* are a *pair* of green balls."

- The first case is an example of [*paronomasia*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/)--wordplay that is based on homophonic or near-homophonic resemblance. The words pear and pair are exact homophones, as are whole and hole, words that sound alike, but are spelled differently and mean different things. A good example of paronomasia based on near homophones is Apple's new slogan for the ipad--Resolutionary (revolutionary).
- The second case qualifies as a *double entendre*. The meaning of "country
  life" turns on two different senses, but not two different spellings.

Based on these remarks, you should now be able to classify this pun. *A pun is its own reword.*

Comment: All puns are paronomasia - OED:"Wordplay based on words which sound alike; an instance of this, a pun." Two words that sound the same in one sentence doesn't make a pun as there is no double meaning. Looking at the two pears and saying "that is a nice pair/pear" would be a pun. The second is not double entendre. A double entendre is a phrase with two meanings, one of which is usually risque, but the second meaning lies outside the phrase itself. "Children make nutritious snacks" has two possible meanings, but doesn't contain a word/phrase that has a double meaning, as'country life' does.

Comment: I down voted this question on the basis of what @RoaringFish had to say

Comment: The classic "pear/pair" double-entendre: *Buxom young woman holding two watermelons:* Can I interest you in these, sir?  
*Man:* Why, what a lovely pair!  
*Woman:* They're not pears, they're melons.  
*Man:* Whatever you call them, they are beautiful.

Comment: That made me laugh, brilliant.

Comment: @Olly: I think the downvote is harsh. I'd regard it as a pun (wordplay), even if it happens to be a rather low-quality pun. Collins defines [pun](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pun) as _the use of words or phrases to exploit ambiguities and innuendoes in their meaning, usually for humorous effect; a play on words._ Note the word "usually" in that definition. The fact that you misspelled the word "pair" indicates some basic level of punning. Had you said, "Those two _apples_ are a pair of green balls," I'd see no pun at all, but I suspect you chose "pears" for a reason.